# How to compare to macros in latex

Tags: if-statement, macros, latex, conditional-statements

I want to compare two macros \Lgiii with the one read in as #1 in a macro called fex

```
\def\fex(#1,#2)
ifx\Lgiii#1
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```

However this does not seem to work and maybe someone has a quick solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compare macros, you need to store the argument inside some macro; this allows you to use `\ifx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\fex(#1,#2){%
  \def\Lgi{#1}% Store first argument in \Lgi
  \ifx\Lgiii\Lgi
    do something
  \else
    do something else
  \fi
}
\def\Lgiii{something \relax + 2}

\begin{document}

\fex(this,that)

\fex(something \relax + 2,that)

\fex(something \relax +2,that)

\end{document}
```